# Android studio error in stack trace

Tags: java, android, sdk

```html
CODE FOR TRYING TO GET ACHST/TOTS




package com.karanvir.ccc;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText number1;
    EditText number2;
    EditText number3;
    EditText number4;
    EditText number5;
    EditText number6;
    EditText number7;
    EditText number8;
    EditText number9;
    EditText number10;
    double ach1;
    double ach2;
    double ach3;
    double ach4;
    double ach5;
    double ach6;
    double ach7;
    double ach8;
    double ach9;
    double ach10;


    EditText answer;
    // setting up our % of grades part
    EditText total0;
    EditText total1;
    EditText total2;
    EditText total3;
    EditText total4;
    EditText total5;
    EditText total6;
    EditText total7;
    EditText total8;
    EditText total9;
    double tot1;
    double tot2;
    double tot3;
    double tot4;
    double tot5;
    double tot6;
    double tot7;
    double tot8;
    double tot9;
    double tot10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUi();



    }


    private void initializeUi() {

        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved2);
        number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved3);
        number4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved4);
        number5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved5);
        number6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved6);
        number7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved7);
        number8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved8);
        number9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved9);
        number10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved10);
        ach1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
        ach2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
        ach3 = Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());
        ach4 = Integer.parseInt(number4.getText().toString());
        ach5 = Integer.parseInt(number5.getText().toString());
        ach6 = Integer.parseInt(number6.getText().toString());
        ach7 = Integer.parseInt(number7.getText().toString());
        ach8 = Integer.parseInt(number8.getText().toString());
        ach9 = Integer.parseInt(number9.getText().toString());
        ach10 = Integer.parseInt(number10.getText().toString());

//Casting our button and the answer field

        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
// setting up our % of grades part
        total0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total0);
        total1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total1);
        total2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total2);
        total3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total3);
        total4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total4);
        total5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total5);
        total6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total6);
        total7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total7);
        total8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total8);
        total9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total9);
        tot1 = Integer.parseInt(total0.getText().toString());
        tot2 = Integer.parseInt(total1.getText().toString());
        tot3 = Integer.parseInt(total2.getText().toString());
        tot4 = Integer.parseInt(total3.getText().toString());
        tot5 = Integer.parseInt(total4.getText().toString());
        tot6 = Integer.parseInt(total5.getText().toString());
        tot7 = Integer.parseInt(total6.getText().toString());
        tot8 = Integer.parseInt(total7.getText().toString());
        tot9 = Integer.parseInt(total8.getText().toString());
        tot10 = Integer.parseInt(total9.getText().toString());


    }
    public void ons(View view) {

        double tots = (tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4 + tot5 + tot6 + tot7 + tot8 + tot9 + tot10);
        double achst= ach1+ach2+ach3+ach4+ach5+ach6+ach7+ach8+ach9+ach10;

        double multi = achst / tots;
        String total2 = String.valueOf(multi);
        answer.setText(total2);

    }
}
```

```html
newest error after recommended




05-14 22:43:08.155 762-871/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-14 22:43:09.185 32300-32300/? E/Zygote: v2
05-14 22:43:09.195 32300-32300/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-14 22:43:09.315 32314-32314/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.525 32330-32330/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.585 32332-32332/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.635 32334-32334/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.695 32337-32337/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.745 32340-32340/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.805 32342-32342/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.855 32352-32352/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.905 32356-32356/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:09.965 32358-32358/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:10.025 32360-32360/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:43:10.365 32300-32300/com.karanvir.ccc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.karanvir.ccc, PID: 32300
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.karanvir.ccc/com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity.initializeUi(MainActivity.java:114)
                                                                      at com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
05-14 22:43:10.435 762-1543/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2175 [05-14 22:43:10.440]
05-14 22:43:10.685 762-32374/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
05-14 22:43:10.685 762-32374/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
05-14 22:43:10.685 762-32374/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
05-14 22:43:17.775 14835-14887/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 7 size : 5Kb duration : 108ms lastUpdatedAfter : 27748 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 2562
05-14 22:43:31.025 2549-2549/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in send_object_removed
05-14 22:43:40.435 762-1543/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 2176 [05-14 22:43:40.442]
```

[enter image description here][1]

```html
New error after trying recommended answer



05-14 22:22:23.795 23560-23560/? E/Zygote: v2
05-14 22:22:23.795 23560-23560/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-14 22:22:23.945 23573-23573/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.165 23590-23590/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.225 23593-23593/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.275 23596-23596/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.335 23598-23598/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.395 23600-23600/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.445 23604-23604/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.505 23612-23612/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.555 23614-23614/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.615 23616-23616/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:24.675 23618-23618/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.ccc-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
05-14 22:22:25.015 23560-23560/com.karanvir.ccc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.karanvir.ccc, PID: 23560
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.karanvir.ccc/com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                      at com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity.initializeUi(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                      at com.karanvir.ccc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
05-14 22:22:25.335 762-23632/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
05-14 22:22:25.335 762-23632/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
05-14 22:22:25.335 762-23632/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
05-14 22:22:31.155 23729-23729/? E/Zygote: v2
05-14 22:22:31.165 23729-23729/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-14 22:22:32.785 23729-23763/? E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
05-14 22:22:32.785 23729-23763/? E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
05-14 22:22:32.785 23729-23763/? E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
05-14 22:22:32.785 23729-23763/? E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

This my main activity code for my project.. I'm a new developer so there might be some really bad simple mistakes.  I am a new developer I should also add. I have included my error in my catalogs also just below.

```
package com.karanvir.ccc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved1);
    EditText number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved2);
    EditText number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved3);
    EditText number4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved4);
    EditText number5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved5);
    EditText number6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved6);
    EditText number7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved7);
    EditText number8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved8);
    EditText number9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved9);
    EditText number10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved10);
    double ach1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
    double ach2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
    double ach3 = Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());
    double ach4 = Integer.parseInt(number4.getText().toString());
    double ach5 = Integer.parseInt(number5.getText().toString());
    double ach6 = Integer.parseInt(number6.getText().toString());
    double ach7 = Integer.parseInt(number7.getText().toString());
    double ach8 = Integer.parseInt(number8.getText().toString());
    double ach9 = Integer.parseInt(number9.getText().toString());
    double ach10 = Integer.parseInt(number10.getText().toString());

    //Casting our button and the answer field

    EditText answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    // setting up our % of grades part
    EditText total0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total0);
    EditText total1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total1);
    EditText total2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total2);
    EditText total3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total3);
    EditText total4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total4);
    EditText total5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total5);
    EditText total6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total6);
    EditText total7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total7);
    EditText total8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total8);
    EditText total9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total9);
    double tot1 = Integer.parseInt(total0.getText().toString());
    double tot2 = Integer.parseInt(total1.getText().toString());
    double tot3 = Integer.parseInt(total2.getText().toString());
    double tot4 = Integer.parseInt(total3.getText().toString());
    double tot5 = Integer.parseInt(total4.getText().toString());
    double tot6 = Integer.parseInt(total5.getText().toString());
    double tot7 = Integer.parseInt(total6.getText().toString());
    double tot8 = Integer.parseInt(total7.getText().toString());
    double tot9 = Integer.parseInt(total8.getText().toString());
    double tot10 = Integer.parseInt(total9.getText().toString());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
```

Comment: can someone please help me solve the error

Comment: can you post some code as well

Comment: ok i have it, im posting it now. i dont know how to use this thing yet properly but ill do my best

Comment: initialize editTexts and double values below *setContentView(..)* method

Comment: could you please show me the code how to do that? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Just like you did for toolbar.

Comment: What does "I am a never developer" mean?

Comment: Move all the findViewById method below setContentView(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText number1, number2.....
    double ach1, ach2....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUi();

     .................
       ....................
     .................

    }


    private void initializeUi() {

        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved2);
        number3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved3);
        number4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved4);
        number5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved5);
        number6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved6);
        number7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved7);
        number8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved8);
        number9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved9);
        number10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achieved10);


        //Casting our button and the answer field

        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        // setting up our % of grades part
        total0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total0);
        total1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total1);
        total2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total2);
        total3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total3);
        total4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total4);
        total5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total5);
        total6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total6);
        total8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total8);
        total9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total9);




    }


    public void ons(View view) {


        ach1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
        ach2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
        ach3 = Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());
        ach4 = Integer.parseInt(number4.getText().toString());
        ach5 = Integer.parseInt(number5.getText().toString());
        ach6 = Integer.parseInt(number6.getText().toString());
        ach7 = Integer.parseInt(number7.getText().toString());
        ach8 = Integer.parseInt(number8.getText().toString());
        ach9 = Integer.parseInt(number9.getText().toString());
        ach10 = Integer.parseInt(number10.getText().toString());

        tot1 = Integer.parseInt(total0.getText().toString());
        tot2 = Integer.parseInt(total1.getText().toString());
        tot3 = Integer.parseInt(total2.getText().toString());
        tot4 = Integer.parseInt(total3.getText().toString());
        tot5 = Integer.parseInt(total4.getText().toString());
        tot6 = Integer.parseInt(total5.getText().toString());
        tot7 = Integer.parseInt(total6.getText().toString());
        tot8 = Integer.parseInt(total7.getText().toString());
        tot9 = Integer.parseInt(total8.getText().toString());
        tot10 = Integer.parseInt(total9.getText().toString());

        double tots = (tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4 + tot5 + tot6 + tot7 + tot8 + tot9 + tot10);
        double achst= ach1+ach2+ach3+ach4+ach5+ach6+ach7+ach8+ach9+ach10;

        double multi = achst / tots;
        String total2 = String.valueOf(multi);
        answer.setText(total2);

    }
```

Comment: variables were never used, and my onclick method doesnt work at all.. all my variables are red

Comment: Please see my edit.. Initialize variable globally and assign it on the method

Comment: @Karanvir1 Your will be fixed by now

Comment: @Karanvir1 initialize all the EditText and double variables globally.

Comment: would you like to see a possible screen shot?

Comment: Yes please. Add a screenshot

Comment: I have added in all the edits and problems i am getting

Comment: Its number format exception because you are trying convert an empty string to a number.

Comment: So if the editext doesnt have any string entered in it. and you are trying to convert it into a number. Thats not possible,

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Should I add something to my edit text string? as a place holder

Comment: In xml iteself set edittext values to "0".. add *andriod:text="0"* for editTexts

Comment: Yes.. You must.

Comment: im not sure what to do, but i included the error msg up above

Comment: Which line is in you *MainActivity.java:114* ??

Comment: tot8 = Integer.parseInt(total7.getText().toString());

Comment: i fixed that line re running it

Comment: ok so it loads up and is running however when i press my button, it returns a value NaN. not the number value i wanted

Comment: Its because somewhere in the code a Number format exception is thrown.

Comment: ill post my code again, all i want is the achieved numbers to divide by the totals in my on click method.